# How can I dynamically change the shape of a clr-icon custom element?

Tags: angular, custom-element, vmware-clarity

In the [Clarity Icon docs](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/icons/how-to-use) they show that you can use the shape attribute to set the icons shape like this:

```
<clr-icon shape="info-circle" size="16"></clr-icon>
```

In my angular template I am using a clr-icon element like this:

```
<clr-icon [shape]="myShape"></clr-icon>
```

And use my component to set the string value of the shape bound to `myShape`:

```
export class MyComponent {
    public myShape = 'volume-up';

    changeShape() {
        if(this.myShape === 'volume-up') {
            this.myShape = 'volume-mute';
            return;
        }
        this.myShape = 'volume-up;
    }
}
```

Using a button (not shown in the template) I want to run the `changeShape()` to dynamically change the shape of the icon but nothing is happening, what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please refer to Angular Template Syntax Binding targets section. Link: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets

[image]

You need to use:

```
[attr.shape]="myShape"
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/m4v5hXMxWRL5ObD3TPaO?p=preview