# ternary operator on shape attribute doesn't work

Tags: html, angular6, vmware-clarity

I am trying to add ternary condition to `shape` which is an icon type `shape="success-standard"` - in  `shape="name.active ? 'success-standard' : 'times-circle'"` that's where I am trying to add a condition for icon type. and  using [shape] directive doesn't work

```html
<clr-dg-row class="man-rcs" *ngFor="let name of visibleNames">
  <clr-dg-cell (click)="handleRowClick(name)" class="tac">
    <clr-icon size="18" shape="name.active ? 'success-standard' : 'times-circle'">
    </clr-icon>
  </clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
```

Normally I would do it like this but that's not what I am looking for in this case

```html
<clr-dg-cell class="tac">
  <clr-icon size="18" *ngIf="name?.active" shape="success-standard" class="is-solid is-success"></clr-icon>
  <clr-icon size="18" *ngIf="!name?.active" shape="times-circle" class="is-solid is-danger"></clr-icon>
</clr-dg-cell>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the shape attribute like this. Icons are our web components, so you have to use this different approach.

`[attr.shape]=“name.active ? ‘success-standard’ : ‘times-circle’”`

See [How can I dynamically change the shape of a clr-icon custom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914238/how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-shape-of-a-clr-icon-custom-element) For more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below

```
<clr-icon size="18" shape="{{name.active == true ? 'success-standard' : 'times-circle'}}">
```

Or

```
<clr-icon size="18" shape="(name?.active == true ? 'success-standard' : 'times-circle')">
```

Hope first code will work

Comment: both dont work error message `  - Can't bind to 'shape' since it isn't a known property of 'clr-icon'.
1. If 'clr-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'shape' input, then verify that it is part of this module.